# What is relationship between the vars in theme of drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I created a theme in Drupal 7 and rendered a node page.

1st, drupal calls the function at page--node.tpl.php:

```
print render($page['content']);
```

2nd, it calls the function at template.php:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  //...
};
```

3rd, it uses node.tpl.php to render the page.

So, what is the relationship between $page['content'] (page--node.tpl.php), $vars(template.php) and variables at node.tpl.php?  Where could I find documentation to answer this question?

Comment: See [overview of Drupal theme files](http://drupal.org/node/171194)

Answer (score 0):

Thats is the drupal theme workflow, i think you need to see the 'Big picture'

[Here](http://drupal.org/node/173880) is explained the theme registry, and can clarify our question

And [here](http://drupal.org/node/171194) and overview of theme files